# Does tmpdir in pytest create a file only when we write to it?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fixtures, pytest-mock

When I use `fp = tmpdir.join("hello.txt")` in pytest, does pytest actually create a file in my temp directory or it creates only when I write `fp.write("hello")`?

Comment: You could try it and see, what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `pytest` will not create the file until you actually write to it. Under the hood, as mentioned in the documentation, `tmpdir` uses [py.path](https://py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/path.html). When you call [join](https://py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/path.html#py._path.local.LocalPath.join) it will lazily get the new path, meaning it does not exist until you actually write something to it.